# Why does the "Oracle error ORA-12506 encountered" error occur?

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to connect my Oracle database to [ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core) web API using a database-first approach.
I created an ErrorLog table and used the scaffold command in Visual Studio package manager console.

When trying to run the following command:

**Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(copied string from tnsnames file);user id=userid; password= .....;Pooling=false;Connection Timeout=120;HA Events = true;Load Balancing = true;Validate Connection = true" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models**
facing **Oracle error ORA-12506 encountered error**.

I installed EntityFramework and oracle.entityframrwork packages in Visual Studio.

What is the exact flow of an Oracle db connection in .NET Core and why does the above error occur?

Comment: A (very brief) search for ORA-12506 leads to [this list of errors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/ORA-12500.html#GUID-BD6AAC21-3F15-4F70-B3C5-064ADCF5EC51) which defines the error as "ORA-12506: TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering". Which tells you what went wrong.

Comment: "oracle.entityframrwork" doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The database service is protected by an Access Control List, and your client is not registered. You will need to work with your DBA to get the client added to the ACL.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/ORA-12500.html#GUID-BD6AAC21-3F15-4F70-B3C5-064ADCF5EC51):

> ORA-12506: TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering
>
> Cause: The client is not present in Service Access Control List.
>
> Action: Add the client's address in Service ACL.